# Using Ext "Neptune" theme with App SDK 2.0

Tags: rally, appsdk2

Now that Rally has changed the default UI for their ALM product, I have noticed that the UI components in my apps don't fit the same styling characteristics as the default UI elements. I think it would look a lot cleaner if I could use Ext's "Neptune" theme: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#basic-panels

Is there a way I can use this theme by default? If it is hosted anywhere within Rally, I think it would be as easy as including the CSS file in the App.html, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.0rc1 is built on Ext 4.1.1a, so I'm not sure if the neptune theme is included or not.  You'll be happy to know that 2.0rc2 is hot off the presses though, and should incorporate most of the new look and feel.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/